# Process data in blocks of 16 bytes

Tags: java, arrays, byte, padding

I am building a crypto tool in java. I got this method :

```
public byte[] blockEncrypt(byte[] b) {
//...
}
```

which takes an array of 16 bytes as argument. But I don't want the user to split bytes himself so I created this method :

```
public byte[] encrypt(final byte[] plain) {

    int remainder = plain.length % blockSize();
    // I create the final array of size modulo blockSize
    byte[] encrypted = new byte[plain.length - remainder + (remainder == 0 ? 0 : blockSize())];
    // Here the array is splitted 
    byte[][] splitted = CryptoUtil.splitBytes(plain, blockSize());

    // I pad the last block if the argument is not modulo blockSize (with '=')
    if (plain.length % blockSize() != 0) {
        byte[] last = new byte[blockSize()];
        CryptoUtil.fill(last, (byte) 0x3D);
        System.arraycopy(splitted[splitted.length - 1], 0, last, 0, splitted[splitted.length - 1].length);
        splitted[splitted.length - 1] = last;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < splitted.length; i++) {
        System.arraycopy(blockEncrypt(splitted[i], 0), 0, encrypted, i * blockSize(), blockSize());
    }
    return encrypted;
}
```

This code doesn't work at all (and is messy). I don't care on how it is achieved at all, I just want to process all the data in argument, 16 bytes per 16 bytes. Does anyone have a method for this ?
The last non-full block should be resized to 16 (by adding null bytes or anything).
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: So your goal is to split a `byte[]` into a `byte[][16]`?

Comment: 1. If you know the "is messy" clean it up, that makes it easier to understand/debiug. 2. Use [PKCS#7 padding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)#PKCS7), null padding does not work with binary data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is over-complicated, but this is what I came up with:

```
public List<byte[]> splitArray(byte[] array, int blockSize) {
    if (array.length < blockSize) {
        // shortcut if array is too small, will pad end with 0s
        return Arrays.asList(Arrays.copyOf(array, blockSize));
    } else if (array.length == blockSize) {
        // shortcut if array length is already blockSize
        return Arrays.asList(array);
    }
    List<byte[]> list = new ArrayList<>();
    int from = 0;
    int to;
    while ((to = from + blockSize) <= array.length) {
        // keep adding to list while array has another blockSize range of elements
        list.add(Arrays.copyOfRange(array, from, to));
        from = to;
    }
    if (from != array.length) {
        // array did not divide into blockSize evenly, fill last block
        // with remaining elements. Pads end with 0s
        byte[] leftOver = new byte[blockSize];
        System.arraycopy(array, from, leftOver, 0, array.length - from);
        list.add(leftOver);
    }
    return list;
}
```

I changed the return type from `byte[][]` to `List<byte[]>` (I found `List` easier to work with).